# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'db' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot to have a lvl system on my discord server, you know if you post you gain exp you level up and so on.
And all this is stored in a database.

Problem : when I do something like
`cursor = await bot.db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO guildData (guild_id,user_id,exp) VALUES(?,?,?),(message.guild.id,message.author.id,1))`

to enter a new user with his exp in the database I have the following error in the terminal:

AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'db'

How to fix it?

**EDIT WHERE I HAVE DEFINED BOT**

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)
```

and the initialise fct

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def initialise(): 
  await bot.wait_until_ready()
  bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("expData.db")
  await bot.db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guildData (guild_id int, user_id int, exp int, PRIMARY KEY (guild_id,user_id))")
```

Comment: Please show where you have defined `bot`?

Comment: edited the error appear when I post messages because the line you see above is in on_message function.

Comment: Why you are doing `bot.db =`? Why not just define a new variable `db` and use that? ie, `db = await aiosqlite.connect("expData.db")` and then just `db.execute`?

Comment: It says db is not defined if I do that. Because I have 3 functions that use db on_message,stats and leaderboard. In stats or leaderboard it will say it's undefined